# composer place git repo to a custom path

Tags: php, drupal, composer-php

How to place git repo to a custom path? I am using composer/Installer. and I have develop a module on git repo. I would like to add it to composer.json but after pull it should be placed web/modules/custom directory. How can i do that.

I added this parts in my composer.json

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/miteshmap/axelerant_custom"
    }
],
"require": {
    "miteshmap/axelerant_custom": "*"
},
"extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
        "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
        "web/modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
        "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
        "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
        "drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your repository on github in your `composer.json` file you need to edit the name to `"miteshmap/commerce"`, change the type as your rule `"web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],` will currently place it in that folder and require `"composer/installers": "~1.0"`

```
{
    "name": "miteshmap/commerce",
    "type": "my-repo",
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "~1.0"
    }
}
```

The rest of your code looks fine.

Comment: looks like the OP changed his question

Comment: It's same, just replaced the         "web/modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],